# PHP: Parsing string into array with nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, nested

I've got the following code for parsing a string into an array of options:

```
$options = 'myvalue, test=123, myarray=[1,2]';

function parse_options($options)
{
    $split = '/,(?=[^\]]*(?:\[|$))/';

    if($options && is_string($options)) 
    {
        $temp_options = preg_split($split, $options);
        $options = array();
        foreach($temp_options as $option) 
        {
            $option = trim($option);
            if(strpos($option,'=')) 
            {
                //Is an option with a value
                list($key, $value) = explode('=',$option);
                if(strpos($value,'[') !== FALSE) 
                {
                    //Is an array of values
                    $value = explode(',', substr($value, 1,-1));
                }
                $options[$key] = $value;
            }
            else 
            {
                $options[] = $option;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        //Return empty array if not a string or is false
        if(!is_array($options)) { $options = array(); }
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Basically it splits by comma unless surrounded by brackets. Then it checks for the = for key->value pairs and then tries to figure out if the value is an array.

This works fine, but I would like to improve it so that it can create nested arrays for something like

```
$options = 'myvalue, test=123, bigwhopper=[ myarray=[1,2], test2=something ]';
```

Which would output

```
Array(
    [0] => myvalue,
    [test] => 123,
    [bigwhopper] => Array(
                [myarray] = Array(
                     [0] => 1,
                     [1] => 2
                ),
                [test] => something
            )
)
```

**I'm certainly no RegExp guru so can someone help me make the function understand nested [] separators?** Also anything to improve the function's performance is highly appreciated as I use this a lot to easily pass options to my controllers.

Comment: Well, you're trying to write a custom unserializer, and it is **not** an easy task. Why do you need to parse such results?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you inventing your own format, over something that's already widely established.

Some options:

- urlencoding does this
- json
- yalm
- php's serialize()

You're inventing a whole new syntax, and standard regex won't even allow this because it has recursion. You basically need to write a parser, so the best place to start if you insist on your own syntax, is to look at parser generators.

http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/parser-and-lexer-generators-for-php/

Comment: I wish I could up vote to 0,5 :) +0,5 to note there are several better solutions, -0,5 because he may really need to do this if the data are given by a third party. (though +1 anyway)

Comment: well I did give him a starting point for writing a parser too ;) thanks for the vote though :P

Comment: The idea was to have a simple and quick way to send some options to a function. A typical use would be something like get_stuff(123, 'limit=5, render=grid, something=[1,5]') which is easy to understand and very quick to write. The options are parsed into an array which can be checked for specific keys and then shape what the get_stuff function (usually getting something from database) will do.

Its mostly a tool to make development easier so instead of array(123, 'limit' => 5, 'render' => 'grid', 'something' => array(1,5)) I can just pass a simple string and let the parser handle the rest.

Comment: So yea, my humble opinion is that this is a bad idea.. How, for example are you going to deal with escaping (for instance, if I want my string to contain a quote, or a comma). You are inventing a new format, and require a parser unless you are ok with 'weird bugs'.

Comment: To be honest I'm not too concerned about that. It's only used to pass simple, typically one word options or an array of options. It's not for inputting anything complex or any real data and is not used by the end user. The code I posted has been quite sufficient until now.

Comment: Well you have your answer. You need recursion, sou you should start writing your parser. And in the meanwhile, I hope I never have to maintain your code ;). Still sounds like a terrible idea

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel by creating a new (incomplete, buggy and slow) parser for your options. Use preexisting solutions :

- serialize
- [getopt](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.getopt.php)
- JSON
- etc